# How Tensorflow decides the CPU utilization when doing the distributed training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cpu, distributed

I am a beginner in using Tensorflow to do distributed training.
So far, my code is working fine. But when I monitor the process, something puzzles me.

I have two CPU compute nodes. Each is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @ 2.70GHz. 32 cores.

By using `tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()`, I am able to distribute the training job to these two CPUs.

Here are some numbers.

Case1: CIFAR10 with Resnet56

Train on single CPU with batch size 64: each CPU core Utilization ~68%

Train on two CPUs with batch size 128 (each CPU got 64): each CPU core Utilization ~68%

Case2: MNIST digit with 5 layer Network

Train on single CPU with batch size 64: each CPU core Utilization ~40%

Train on two CPUs with batch size 128 (each CPU got 64): each CPU core Utilization ~15%

My question here is, why in case2, when the job is distributed, the CPU utilization goes down? I suppose the CPU utilization should somehow remain ~40% since each CPU gets the same batch size with the single CPU training situation.

Here is how the model compiled. I don't know if this has some relationship with the optimizer or something inside tensorflow.

`model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001),
      metrics=['accuracy'])`

Update: I also monitor the bandwidth between two nodes. ~386Mbit/s. They are connected through 1G Port. Is it possible that the bottleneck is the network connection? But I also suppose the bandwidth is enough for ~386*2Mbit/s < 1G.

Thank you so much!